# How MySQL is rounding numbers by default?

Tags: mysql, rounding

Let's say we have table with two columns:

- number_a DECIMAL(6,3)
- number_b DECIMAL(6,2)

My question is: how mysql wil round numbers in this query:

`UPDATE table SET number_b = number_a`

Truncate, round to half down, half up?

Edit: Link to docs is all I need. I want to make sure there is no magic setting which make it works different on different server configuration

Comment: It will round (yes half down, half up) to 2 dp

Comment: @F4r-20 is there any setting in mysql.ini / official docs?

Comment: What are you trying to **achieve**

Comment: @F4r-20 i want to use this query in application, but I want to make sure rounding works in same way on every server, on every configuration

Comment: obviously i will use `ROUND()` function if necessary

Comment: I'm pretty sure rounding is universal. Everything rounds the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will effectively use ROUND().  You can see a simple example table here with the results of an UPDATE taking the 3dp values into the 2dp column : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de5b7/1

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    3dp DECIMAL(6,3),
    2dp DECIMAL(6,2)
);

INSERT INTO test (3dp,2dp) VALUES 
    (1.114,0),
    (1.115,0),
    (1.116,0);

UPDATE test SET 2dp = 3dp;

SELECT * FROM test;
```

Producing result

```
3DP     2DP
---------------
1.114   1.11
1.115   1.12
1.116   1.12
```